# How to Count Sheet Rows and Display each Row Count on Totals Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-365

I have a sheet that has rows added to it each month (10,000 and growing). I have a module that copies the rows for each State to it's own sheet.  I'm trying to add a Totals sheet that has each State's row total.  It needs to automatically update when rows are added to All States sheet. I have attached examples of what I have and what I'm trying to achieve. Attachments, (1) All States sheet, (2) Arizona, (3) California, (4) New Mexico. And (5), Totals sheet, I'm trying to add.
[All States sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLS3t.png)[Arizona](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xZzE.png)[Califonia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWdIJ.png)[New Mexico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfrQ8.png)[Totals Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URr7m.png)

I've tried permutations of Sheet.Rows.Count in a For loop, but it hasn't come out right yet.

Comment: it's been a while since I've dug into VBA, but I think you want to check out UsedRange for the sheet which should get you the row & column count for what cells are used in that sheet

Comment: Use `COUNTA()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")-1` so it'll count the number of rows in column `A` and either adjust the range accordingly or take away the number of header/total cells you have which in this case is the `-1` in the formula

Comment: OK, that will work one time. I will be constantly adding dozens of new rows each month to the main sheet, which will propagate rows to each state's sheet.  The Totals sheet needs to automatically get the new row count for each of the states sheet and update the row count for each state on the Totals sheet.

Comment: I have been tweaking this code, but can't get it work,

Comment: Sub TotalsRowCount ()
 For Each sh In Activeworkbook.Worksheets
  sh.Name & sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Next sh
End Sub

Comment: So you are copying all the rows from each individual state to the 'All States' sheet?
`=COUNTIF(A:A,"Arizona")`